# Boolean Expression Evaluator PHP

Tags: php, boolean

I want to be able to evaluate a boolean expression like below:

```
Given: A, B, C

Evaluate:
      A and B  // output: true
      A and D  // output: false
       A or D  // output: true
A and (B or D) // output: true
```

In the above example, the given are only string literals. It's evaluating the existence of the tag not the value of. In addition, it should be able to recognize grouping using parenthesis.

Is there a way to do this without creating a custom parser in PHP? Or if not, is there any library out there that we can use?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (A and B) ? true : false
```

if A is null, then it refers to 0 (0x00 in hex) which will AND anything to 0.
Is this what you're looking for,OR did I misunderstood?